# want to display keywords and their translations using mysql Query

Tags: mysql

i have a situation where, there are two tables one is keyword and second is translations in mysql

```
Keywords
------------
ID    Keyword
------------
1     Hi
2     How are you
```

Here is second table

```
Translations
----------------------------------------
keyword_id      translation   Lang_id
------------------------------------------
1               Hello          1
1               Hej            4
1               Hey            2
```

so i want to display list of keywords (even if they are not in translation's table) and their translations,

i am using this query

```
SELECT keywords.keyword, translation 
FROM keywords 
LEFT JOIN translations on keywords.id = translations.keyword_id 
WHERE lang_id = 4
```

as a result i want list of keywords (Hi, how are you) and List of translations (Hej)
and if there is no translation of how are you then it should display some default text like lang_id 1

Comment: so what output you get from your query?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT keywords.keyword, COALESCE(translation, "lang_id 1")
FROM keywords 
LEFT JOIN translations on keywords.id = translations.keyword_id 
WHERE lang_id = 4
```

That will show you the default string you set instead of `NULL` when there are no corresponding records...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT keywords.keyword, Case When translation is null Then "Lang_ID1" Else translation End)
from keywords 
LEFT JOIN translations on keywords.id = translations.keyword_id 
where lang_id = 4
```